# How can I install yajl in windows?

Tags: python, json, cmd, pip, yajl

I would like to install yajl-py. I tried this: `pip install yajl-py`. 
But there is an error:

```
OSError : Yajl shared object cannot be found . Please install Yajl and confirm it is on your shared lib path.
```

Have you got any idea?

Comment: Do [these instructions](https://github.com/LearningRegistry/LearningRegistry/wiki/Windows-Installation-Guide#yajl) work?

Comment: unfortunately `yajl-py` was never tested on windows. It should not be a lot of work to get it up and running, the problem is most probably that `yajl-py` does not look for `.dll` version of the so. If you open an issue on https://github.com/pykler/yajl-py it should be looked at asap.

Comment: Has this issue been fixed because I am having the same problem getting it to detect the .dll file where my yajl is stored?

Comment: I didn't find a solution so I used ijson library.